# Printing values of a String List in flutter without invoking the null error

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have this list

```
List? mcq;
```

Now, when after adding values in it, when I try to print the values on the app screen using the Text widget it gives a null error.

```
child: TextButton(
    child: Text(mcq?[0]),
    onPressed: () => {}),
```

It says type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'.

If I remove the ? it says [] cannot be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be null.

Then how do I print the values of a list using Text widget?

Answer (score 1):

You need set a default value incase it get `null`, like this:

```
child: TextButton(
    child: Text(mcq?[0]?? "some thing"),//<---- add this
    onPressed: () => {}),
```